# Spring RestTemplate: getting 403 forbidden for multipart/form-data but working with curl

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, resttemplate, http-status-code-403

I am using spring rest-template to POST request `form-data` of 1 file and 1 string parameter, here is code:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer ...");
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    File file=new File("src\main\resources\test.json");
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    byte[] fileBytes = toByteArray(in);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
            .builder("form-data")
            .name("file")
            .filename("test.json")
            .build();
    fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
    fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<byte[]> fileEntity =
            new org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<>(fileBytes, fileMap);

    MultiValueMap< String, Object > body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("stringFormInput", "xyz");
    body.add("file", fileEntity);
    org.springframework.http.HttpEntity< MultiValueMap< String, Object > > entity =
            new org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity< JsonNode > responseEntity =
            restTemplate.postForEntity("https://uploadFile", entity, JsonNode.class);
```

But I'm getting `403 FORBIDDEN` response

However, If I use curl command below, it executes successfully

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://uploadFile' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
--form 'file=@/D:/resources/test.json' \
--form 'stringFormInput=xyz' \
```

I also tried with `httpClient`, still, it is 403 with no any cause message

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://uploadFile");
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer ...");

File file=new File("src\main\resources\test.json");
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "test.json");
builder.addTextBody("stringFormInput", "xyz", ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

post.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

**EDIT**

For now I did a workaround by executing curl from JAVA

```
    File file=new File("src\main\resources\test.json");
    String[] command = {"curl", "--location",
            "--request", "POST", "https://uploadFile",
            "--header", "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            "--header", "Authorization: Bearer ...",
            "-F", "file=" + "@"+file.getPath(),
            "--form", "stringFormInput=xyz"};

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    String curlResult = "";
    String line = "";

    try {
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            curlResult = curlResult + line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need to add headers for the httpclient request.

Comment: added `Content-Type` and `Authorization` header, still same issue

Comment: this one might be helpful
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload

Comment: yes, I tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

So I faced a similar problem that cURL was executing properly but Spring code was giving 403.
The problem lies with the target which is receiving this request. Few web servers like Nginx required mandatory headers like "User-Agent" by default which can be disabled.

By default, Spring doesn't pass any extra header. Try adding "User-Agent" if the target is using Ngnix or find what web server they are using.

Sharing my code for reference.

1. This code gave 403

   HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
2. this code worked fine.

   HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
   httpHeaders.add("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.26.3");

Comment: I tried with header `("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.26.3")` still it gave 403, and yes the server is ngnix.